# How Caching an RDD works in case of multiple actions on a persisted RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, caching, rdd

```
val logList: RDD[String] = ...
val errorLogs = logList.filter(_.contains("Error")).persist()
//first action   
val first100 = errorLogs.take(100)
//second action
val count = errorLogs.count
```

How will persist work this case ? In the case of below code

```
val errorLogs = logList.filter(_.contains("Error")).take(100)
```

Spark will not scan through all the logs sinceSpark knows that we are interested only in 100 lines of logs. But what will happen when we cache this RDD and invoke multiple actions on it, first action requiring only few records and later ones needing the whole RDD to be transformed.

Will it cache the records when the first action is invoked ? Or will it cache only partial records which were needed for the first action when first action is invoked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How `cache` works**:

- `cache` and `persist` are lazy -  if no action is called on the `RDD` marked for caching data is not persisted. Similarly if partition is not evaluated data is not persisted.
- `cache` persists whole partitions. It cannot persist single record or a fraction of partition. If data is marked for caching, and partition is at least partially evaluated, Spark will evaluate it fully and attempt to persist.

**How `limit` works**:

- First `limit` evaluates the first partition. If all records required by limit can be collected from the first partition the job finishes.
- If not Spark increases number of partitions to be evaluated by `spark.rdd.limit.scaleUpFactor`. If all records required by limit can be collected from these partitions the job finishes. Otherwise this step repeats.

This means that:

- `val first100 = errorLogs.take(100)` will cache at least the first partition. If the first partition doesn't contain 100 records it will evaluate and cache subsequent partitions until it gets to 100 records or evaluates a full dataset.
- `val count = errorLogs.count` will evaluate all partitions and cache remaining partitions if possible.
- `val errorLogs = logList.filter(_.contains("Error")).take(100)` will work almost exactly the same as `errorLogs.take(100)`. The only impact of `filter` is that `limit` might have to evaluate more data. If all lines contain `Error` the result is the same as for the first step.

  If this runs after the first two steps, and data is fully cached and haven't been evicted, it will use data from cache.

Answer (score 6):

In this case Spark will cache only the minimum number of partitions required to collect 100 records (due to take implementation, the actual number can be higher).

Only the second is guaranteed to cache all records.

Comment: Seems reasonable, but. So, taking the 1st case,let me check with you: Assuming the log file has 22 partitions based on disk size, then, if all the errors reside on 12 partitions --> and that comprises 2.2M records, say, then what is the minimum number of records required to collect 100 records, given the general principle of RDD parallel processing and things occurring in parallel? If we understand that, then we know the answer, and most likely you do? Thus? That said I find the documentation for this hard to find.

Comment: Only the second is guaranteed to cache all records ...  Do you mean val count = errorLogs.count  OR val errorLogs = logList.filter(_.contains("Error")).take(100). Not sure I get this.

Comment: This is hard stuff, not well explained imho. The question is what is the persisted RDD.

Comment: @thebluephantom: The second one means, the call to the action errorLogs.count. Because count will have to scan through the entire dataset to get the actual result. So during this action, errorLogs would be cached completely.

Comment: That seems to make sense, but my first question could mean in fact all is cached or more than the minimum is cached due to 1) parallellization anyway and 2) if no records found it would cache all as it would have to scan all to decide that

Comment: So, the other interesting thing is: persist is at errorLogs level, is that not what gets persisted / cached eventually? They are the subset of data surely, not the entire dataset at source? May be I am confusing an issue here ... Sure they are all read, but not all need be persisted ...